# Stack Overflow is currently offline for maintenance

Tags: discussion

Is this scheduled maintenance? When I check https://twitter.com/StackStatus or http://stackstatus.net/, I can't find any details about this maintenance.

[image]

Comment: Unlikely, given that it's pretty late US time and scheduled maintenance *would* be announced weeks in advance.

Comment: Mod candidates!! Here's your chance to shine. Unfortunately not much can be done about 503 without server level access.

Comment: There is tweet  update about the issue [`We are aware of a SQL load issue affecting Stack Overflow and are accessing it now.`](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1107498291065839616)

Comment: @nightgaunt Could you elaborate? Not sure there's anything that candidates (or even current mods) can do here

Comment: @Rob Really sorry if it sounded mean. Being in web field for 6 years, I know nothing can be done without server logs and access. That was a feeble attempt of a joke since current mod elections were going on.

Comment: @nightgaunt I didn't take it as being mean :) Just wasn't sure what you were getting at

Answer (score 5):

This is not a scheduled maintenance, but something wrong with an SQL server, or generally, an unexpected outage:

[image: tweet]

Nick Craver said the systems are up again at 4:42:24 AM UTC.

[image: tweet]

Click the image to go to Nick's original tweets.